# App-defined Configs (Mappings, Data Sources, etc.) to be Used in Gateway Code

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, lucee, application.cfc

In my docker setup, I’d like to get away from using `lucee-web.xml.cfm` to set things up. I’d rather use application-defined configs (configured in `Application.cfc`. However, there’s one snag: One of my Lucee services uses a file watcher gateway.

The gateways run in a weird, standalone context, and I don’t know if it’s even possible to set/use anything but admin-defined configurations (e.g., data sources, mappings, etc.).

Are gateways/listeners incompatible with app-defined configs or is there a way to do it?

(Originally posted here: https://dev.lucee.org/t/app-defined-configs-to-be-used-in-gateway-code/6194)